# Deleting zero after final number

Tags: matlab, matrix, zero

I have a question about how to delet extra zero from a matrix after final number.

```
A= [5 4 0 2 3 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Result:

```
B= [5 4 0 2 3 8 9];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` based approach -

```
A(1:find(A,1,'last')) %// find the last nonzero index and index A until that
```

`nonzeros + find` based approach for A with at least one non-zero entry -

```
nnzA = nonzeros(A) %// Get all non zero entries 
A(1:find(A==nnzA(end))) %// Get the index of last nonzero entry and keep A until that
```

`strfind` based approach for A with at least one non-zero entry -

```
pattern_start = strfind([A~=0 0],[1 0])%//indices of all patterns of [nonzero zero]
A(1:pattern_start(end)) %// Index A until the last pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

If `A` is assured to contain at least one nonzero value, you can do it using `max`:

```
[~, ind] = max(A(end:-1:1)~=0);
A(end-ind+2:end) = [];
```

Or

```
[~, ind] = max(cumsum(A~=0));
A(ind+1:end) = [];
```

---

Or, in the general case, if you don't mind a warning :-)

```
A = deblank(A);
```

Comment: If A is all zeros, it would complicate the matters for both of us! Guess the `deblank` and `find(...'last')` would work then.